# Bootstrap: Typeahead Ajax Update Data

Tags: jquery, twitter, bootstrap, ajax, php

День добрый есть у меня такой код:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function city_load()
{
var city = $("input[name='city']").val();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/authentication/city_load',
data: "city="+city,
dataType: "html",
success: function(data) {
$("input[name='city']").attr('data-source', data);
},
error:  function(xhr, str){
alert('Возникла ошибка');
}
});
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="city" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='' onKeyPress="city_load();">
```

Собственно сами вопросы:

1. Как изменить реагирование на кнопки (ввел одну букву в `var city = пустота`, ввел вторую букву в `var city` = попадает значение первой кнопки и так далее)
2. После получения данных, и подмене их в `data-source input` поля, поиск не работает. Если полученные данные в ручную изменить в `data-source`, тогда по ним возможен поиск.

Кто что посоветует?(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посоветую почитать, как правильно нужно делать ajax-запросы для заполнения автокомплита. Вот первый пример на [wadya.pp.ua](http://wadya.pp.ua/2013/01/23/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-ajax-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE/), вот [второй пример на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12097876/238336). Обратите внимание, что параметр source является функцией, выполняющей ajax-запрос. У вас должно быть как-то так:

```
$('input[name="city"]').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.post(
                       '/authentication/city_load', 
                       { city: query },
                       function (data) {
                            return process(data.options);
                        }, 'json');
        }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло =) вот только пришлось с генерацией json который ему нужен поиграть =)