# Twitter Boostrap Typehead: автозаполнение полей

Tags: twitter

Здраствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, допилить авто заполнение полей при помощи `typehead`, сам `AJAX` я не знаю, пытался делать по аналогии [Автокомплит с использованием ajax при помощи Twitter Bootstrap typeahead](http://wadya.pp.ua/2013/01/23/автокомплит-с-использованием-ajax-при-по/). 
Есть поле в котором выводятся города, пользователь начинает вводить название, остальное дополняется

VIEW:

```
<input type="text" id="city_search" name="city" data-provide="typeahead"/>

  <script>
    $('#city_search').typeahead({
      source : function(typeahead, query) {
          return $.post('user/ajax/getcityname', {
              query : name
          }, function(data) {
              return typeahead.process(JSON.parse(data));
          });
      },
      property : 'city_name_ru'
    });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
public function action_getcityname() {
    $name=Request::current()->post('name');
    $cities = ORM::factory('City')
                        ->where('city_name_ru', 'LIKE', '%' . $name . '%')
                        ->find_all()
                        ->as_array('id','city_name_ru');

    echo json_encode($cities);
}
```

Comment: Осталось показать, какой JSON получается на выходе `action_getcitiname()` - и тогда будет всё ясно.

Comment: примерно вот такой {"17849":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430","17850":"\u041f\u043e\u0434\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a","17851":"\u041a\u043e\u043b\u043e\u043c\u043d ,часть кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я ваш фреймворк к сожалению не знаю... но необходимо сделать что-то вроде:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($cities);$i++)
{
    $cinies_new[] = $cinies[$i]["name"];
}
echo json_encode($cities_new);
```

т.е города должны быть не:

```
{"17849":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430"}
```

а

```
{"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430"}
```

У меня лично только после этого `Typeahead` заработал [Bootstrap: Typeahead Ajax Update Data](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/214737/php-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-update-data).

Comment: да сейчас заработало ) спс